# How use email in .ENV file Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

I'm trying to set the email in a .env file to then be able to use it in nodemailer.

my .env file it's like this:

```
// variables used for email
SERVICE=gmail
SERVICE_PORT=465
EMAIL= xxx.xxx.10@gmail.com
PASSWORD= nxxxxxxxxxx
```

On email after the @ the vscode send an error and the result is undefined..

If I try to use it without @gmail.com, the vscode sends an error after the number..

I'm just be able to use it if I create an email without numbers...

Can someone help me?

Comment: There should not be a space after `=` and strings that contain complex symbols should probably be encapsulated with quotes, e.g `"xxx@gmail.com"`. You could also try to escape the `@` with `\@`

Comment: no space should do the trick. Usally you dont need to escape values in an env file.

Comment: @zanderwar I already take the space of bewteen =.
but when I try to encapsulate the email with quotes the result return undefined..

Comment: @TheFool `MY_VAR=ABC#123` = `ABC`.

Comment: @JohnBaxter does not sound like the .env file is being loaded correctly, or it's being overridden with an empty value, i'm surprised `undefined` is being returned though instead of `null`. Did you try `\@`

Comment: @zanderwar, hash is a special case because its treated as comment. Although I argue that any implementation that treats is as comment if it's not on its own line, is bad or perhaps even buggy. You certainly don't need to escape a @ sign. At least, I have never seen this. I am using URLs with @ sign all the time.

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning the package with which you read the env file.

Comment: Can't reproduce it using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)